# Таргетинговая реклама

Tags: ads

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы узнать как работает таргетинговая реклама, а именно со стороны программирования. Гугл напрочь отказывается давать нормальные результаты, только для маркетологов и прочие статейки, которые не показывают кухню изнутри. Хотелось бы почитать как ее использовать самому, почему, когда я поискал товар в интернете, то мне тут же его предлагают в рекламе. Пришлите пожалуйста ссылки на материалы.

Comment: Поскольку [ответы-ссылки не приветствуются на Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/181100), вопросы их предполагающие так же не приветствуются. А без ссылок тут будет не обойтись ввиду вопиющей всеобъемлющести вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это хорошо показано в документальном сериале Do not track: https://donottrack-doc.com/en/intro/ - это интерактивный сериал.

Если кратко: когда вы что-то поискали и перешли на сайт, то сайт знает, по какому запросу вы его нашли. А вместе с ним это знают все партнерские сети аналитики и рекламы. Эти сети запоминают запрос, равно как и сотни других запросов, они собирают всю возможную и невозможную информацию о вас, хранят ее годами и забираясь как можно глубже в вашу частную жизнь, предлагают именно то, что вы бы купили в этот момент.

Анализировать вас можно не только по запросам к сайтам, но и по троянам в приложениях (вообще это называется "партнерские модули", но ведут они себя хуже последнего вируса), по настоящим вирусам. Чего только люди не сделают, чтобы заработать копеечку. Лучше бы спам рассылали, не так много вреда это приносило.